# Using company mode to complete sentence

Tags: completion, company-mode

As I understand, company mode can help complete the word, but not a sentence. I would like to complete a fragment of sentence.
I would like to complete fragment e.g. "portal and hepatic doppler" but not like "portal-and-hepatic-dopler" as is usual with programming. I do not wish to use abbreviation expansion

I'm looking for a solution to be used with emacs-org.

Answer (score 0):

Rencently, I use TabNine with Company-mode to complete words and short sentence in Org-mode. And it provide me a very good experice, maybe you can try it and enjoy it.

https://github.com/TommyX12/company-tabnine

my integration is as below:

```
(require 'company-tabnine)

;; The free version of TabNine is good enough,
;; and below code is recommended that TabNine not always
;; prompt me to purchase a paid version in a large project.
(defadvice company-echo-show (around disable-tabnine-upgrade-message activate)
  (let ((company-message-func (ad-get-arg 0)))
    (when (and company-message-func
               (stringp (funcall company-message-func)))
      (unless (string-match "The free version of TabNine only indexes up to" (funcall company-message-func))
        ad-do-it))))

;; TabNine
(add-to-list 'company-backends #'company-tabnine)
```

[image]

Comment: It works quite erratically in non-coding environment